# populate SWT table with database content

Tags: java, mysql, swt

I am using PhpMyAdmin to save my data in database. I have a SWT table to populate with database content.

here is my code..

```
public static void fetchDatafromDB(String StartIndex, String FinalIndex) {
    try {
        Class.forName(GlobalVariables.SQL_driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(GlobalVariables.DB_url + GlobalVariables.DB_name, GlobalVariables.DB_Username, GlobalVariables.DB_password);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT  `From`, `To`, `IDno`, `TimeStamp` FROM `callsheet` WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '" + StartIndex + "' AND '" + FinalIndex + "'";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
                // System.out.print(rs.getString(i));
                item.setText(i, rs.getString(i));
            }
            // System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (Exception P) {
        P.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

it worked.

Now I am getting some problem with tabling the DB content in my swt table. What my program does, is that, it sets the selected (defined by limit in program above) content of DB in one row (one by one manner) but I want the next row of DB table to be tabled in next row of SWT table. Could you suggest something about this? ! [Screenshot of my swtTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2pu5.png)

Comment: @AJ. Your link contains code for Swing, OP is asking for SWT though.

Comment: @Baz Ohh yaa.. sorry for that.

Comment: @Baz How to resolve this issue any idea ?

Comment: @Amit.D I don't think I understand your question. Can you elaborate or maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: @Baz Instead of System.out.println() in above code. can you suggest some method which will bring the server content automatically in next row of my swt table (I have this table initialized with heading  added with it, all i need is to fetch the data from server to populate the entire table). Right now entire server content get displayed in just one row of my table(very fast one by one).                         ................just added the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
public static void fetchDatafromDB(String startIndex, String finalIndex) {
    try {
        Class.forName(GlobalVariables.SQL_driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(GlobalVariables.DB_url + GlobalVariables.DB_name, GlobalVariables.DB_Username, GlobalVariables.DB_password);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT  `FROM`, `To`, `IDno`, `TimeStamp` FROM `callsheet` WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '" + startIndex + "' AND '" + finalIndex + "'";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        TableItem item;
        while (rs.next()) {
            // Create a new TableItem for each entry in the result set (each row)
            item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
                // Populate the item (mind the index!!)
                item.setText(i - 1, rs.getString(i));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Amit.D No problem. Always glad when I can help.